# Auto Reconnect NAS drives

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1, nas

I have a Windows 8.1 machine that connects to my Network wirelessly.
I have two NAS drives plugged into a wireless router.

The NAS drives are set to auto-start so they don't run when computer is down.

On starting the laptop, a signal is clearly sent via the wireless network as the NAS drives start up.  They take about 1 minute from "wake up" until the light stops flashing and the shares are enabled.

Windows 8.1 goes to desktop a little quicker than the shares become available though, and I receive the message that Windows could not reconnect my shares.  Clicking on the disconnected share in My Computer then connects it.

I have one account on the laptop, it is an admin level account, there is no password, Windows boots straight to desktop.

My question is; does anyone know of any method to make the network connection "wait" for the NAS to fully wake up and and the shares to become available?

**EDITED: 17/10/2016.**  Answer removed and posted as an answer

Comment: My NAS drives go into hibernation after 5 minutes of inactivity, but they power up in about 4 seconds, which causes no reboot problems with any of the machines which use them. Maybe you use the wrong power-down mode? Other than that you can set a boot-up script which waits a minute, then reconnects the shares. Though I have found that `explorer` will mark as disconnected any shares unavailable on boot-up, but it will remake the connection on opening the share after it becomes available again. My network has a mix of WinXP and Win10 machines connected by LAN and WiFi, all sharing the NAS.

Comment: @AFH Many many thanks for the response; after more research (didn't want to get another -1 ... :-) ) I discovered two methods that work... I was going to edit the question and leave it up for others:

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Rather than edit the question, you should submit your own answer and accept it. This is normal practice on the site, and it allows anyone finding the question to see immediately that it has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question but in doing so found two methods that may be of interest to others.  I have elected then to leave the "question" posted and supply my two findings as an answer (Thanks to AFH for the advice)

1)  Create a netlogon.bat file and change the delay to whatever value you choose - 60 seconds?  Then network connection would not attempt to connect for that time.
The syntax for that (for others who may be interested) is:

Bring up a CMD window and type :

```
net use /persistent:no <hit enter to make shares non persistent>  
net use * /del /yes <hit enter to delete any existing shares>  
notepad "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\netlogon.bat"
```

hit enter - this will bring up a notepad and ask if you wish to create this file

in the notepad enter:

```
@echo off  
set delay=60 <or whatever delay you choose>  
ping localhost -n %delay%  
net use X: \\NASname\ShareName
```

substituting of course your shares and devices for "NASname" and "ShareName"

This will create your shares after a set delay

2) This is what I am trying:
Download "MapDrive.exe" from http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/free-downloads?did=5 and put the executable into C:\Windows or somewhere else in the search path.

use "net use" from the CMD window to again set persistence to "no" and delete existing shares (as above)

Then again from CMD Window enter:

```
notepad "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\netlogon.bat"
```

but in this batch file enter:

```
C:\Windows\MapDrive.exe X: \\NASname\ShareName 60
```

for however many shares you have.

On startup, this will start trying to reconnect the shares until the specified timeout (in this case 60 seconds) is reached.  You can set the timeout to what you desire

Using a batch file will produce a CMD window whilst it runs.  If this troubles you, you can create shortcuts to execute each individual command in the Startmenu.

A shortcut may be better if you have only one or two shares to re-connect

I hope this information is of use to others